# How can I add multiple object references prior to saving a record using Mongoose and Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am saving a record to my MongoDB database and am encountering a multiple save error when I attempt to add multiple object references to the record.

I have tried to change the way my code handles promises with .then and async/await functions but I do not think I am addressing the root cause of the problem.

Here is the code I am working with.

### MENU SCHEMA

```
const MenuSchema = new Schema({
  description: String,
  title: String,
  notes: String,
  _menuItems: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "menuItems"
    }
  ]
});

mongoose.model("menus", MenuSchema);
module.export = MenuSchema;
```

### MENU ITEM SCHEMA

```
const MenuItemSchema = new Schema({
  imageURL: String,
  name_en: String,
  name_es: String,
  type_en: String,
  type_es: String,
  description_en: String,
  description_es: String,
  dietaryCallouts: [String],
  price: Number
});

mongoose.model("menuItems", MenuItemSchema);

module.export = MenuItemSchema;
```

### MENU CONTROLLER

```
create(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const { description, title, notes } = req.body;
      const { _menuItems } = req.body;

      const menu = new Menu({
        description,
        title,
        notes,
        _menuItems: []
      });

      let counter = 0;
      _menuItems.forEach(function(i) {
        counter++;
        MenuItem.findOne({ _id: i }).then(menuItem => {
          menu._menuItems.push(menuItem);
          if (counter === _menuItems.length) {
            menu.save().then(menu => {
              res.send(menu);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(422).send(err);
    }
  }
```

The expected result of the code is to loop through all of the menuItems ids, find them in their respective model, push them into the _menuItems array, and after all items have been added, save the menu object.

The error message that I receive is: "ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel."

The object is saved, but only 1 of the menu items have been saved to the database instead of all of them.

For some reason the save function is getting called multiple times even though the logic flow should only execute once.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you are trying to create a new menu with the given menuItems.

So you do it simply like this: (there is no need to loop)

```
router.post("/create-menu-and-items", async (req, res, next) => {

  try {
    const { description, title, notes, _menuItems } = req.body;

    let menu = new Menu({ description, title, notes, _menuItems });
    menu = await menu.save();

    res.status(201).send(menu);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(422).send(err);
  }
});
```

With this when you post to this url, response will be like this ( I assume you will send the existing menu item ids in the body:

```
{
    "_menuItems": [
        "5dc81674ed5a8a3f78356779",
        "5dc81680ed5a8a3f7835677a",
        "5dc8168bed5a8a3f7835677b"
    ],
    "_id": "5dc8180990b714224462fb2b",
    "description": "Menu 1 description",
    "title": "Menu 1 title",
    "notes": "Menu 1 notes",
    "__v": 0
}
```

This will be extra info, but if in the future you want to add menu items to an existing menu, you can do like this:

```
router.post("/add-menu-items-to-menu/:id", async (req, res, next) => {

  try {
    const { _menuItems } = req.body;

    let menu = await Menu.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $push: { _menuItems } }, { new: true });

    if (menu) {
      res.status(200).send(menu);
    } else {
      res.status(400).send("Menu not found for this id");
    }

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(422).send(err);
  }
});
```

Body:

```
{

    "_menuItems": ["5dc81694ed5a8a3f7835677c", "5dc816a5ed5a8a3f7835677d"]
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "_menuItems": [
        "5dc81674ed5a8a3f78356779",
        "5dc81680ed5a8a3f7835677a",
        "5dc8168bed5a8a3f7835677b",
        "5dc81694ed5a8a3f7835677c",
        "5dc816a5ed5a8a3f7835677d"
    ],
    "_id": "5dc81b134c92ae2884c2468c",
    "description": "Menu 1 description",
    "title": "Menu 1 title",
    "notes": "Menu 1 notes",
    "__v": 0
}
```